# Reuse of class in file with main()

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, redefinition

How can I reuse a class that is in a file that already has a main method? E.g. I would like to use struct foo that another developer wrote in foo.cpp in my own program, main.cpp:

```
//-- foo.cpp --
struct foo {
  int bar;
};
int main() {
  return 0;
}
//-- end foo.cpp --

//-- main.cpp --
#include "foo.cpp"
int main() {
  foo f;
  f.bar = 1;
  return f.bar;
}
//-- end main.cpp
```

main.cpp will not compile using g++ 4.4.4, giving the errors:

```
main.cpp: In function "int main()":
main.cpp:2: error: redefinition of "int main()"
foo.cpp:4: error: "int main()" previously defined here
```

I cannot extract the main method from foo.cpp because I do not control that code. In the actual codebase I am dealing with, struct foo is more complicated so I cannot copy it into main.cpp, since it would be unmaintainable.

Comment: You separate the class and the `main` function into two separate files. Why are you trying to do this any other way?

Comment: You're missing the point, @ChrisLutz -- he didn't write `foo.cpp`. It contains a class he wants to use, along with a `main`.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill - I had assumed that this was all part of the same codebase. I now realize that this was perhaps an incorrect assumption, but I don't think that changes what the answer should be.

Answer (score 1):

place the struct foo inside a header

```
foo.h
#ifndef _STRUCT_FOO
#define _STRUCT_FOO
struct foo {
  int bar;
};
#endif
```

include that wherever you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a preprocessor define to make `main` into a macro that expands to, for example, `not_main`, while you're compiling `foo.cpp`; i.e.,

```
g++ -Dmain=not_main foo.cpp
```

Comment: Also possible is `namespace baz {` / `#include "file.cpp"` / `};` so that `baz::foo` refers to the struct, and `baz::main` would be the other main function. If all the code for `foo` is in `file.cpp` it ought to work.

Comment: I shudder at these hacks, but sometimes you have to do what you have to do. If you are lucky, you live to regret it :) The namespace solution is much better than redefining main.

Comment: If you `#include "file.cpp"` you don't later need to compile `file.cpp`, because it's directly `#include`d in the other file (which presumably _will_ be compiled).

Comment: foo.cpp is compiled by complicated auto-generated Makefile's so this won't work easily. @ChrisLutz all the code for foo is not in file.cpp so that didn't work. Thanks for the attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Non-coding solution: go talk to the people who maintain the code in question. Offer to refactor it for them!

Comment: + Over 9000, would use again.

Comment: An offering of alcohol is traditional in *most* programming cultures :)

Comment: I would but I think she's asleep and I want it tonight :)

Comment: @xnx - Do it tonight and explain why you did it in the morning. What are the chances it'll be a problem?